# C# Soundplayer unable to play from wav stream

Tags: c#, sharepoint, translate

I'm trying to integrate the Speak Method from Bing Translate.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512420.aspx

Using the exact sample codes for PHP, i could play the wav file. However, when i'm using the C# sample code for my Sharepoint web part, i'm not able to play the wav file at all.

Am i missing out on something?

```
private void SpeakMethod(string authToken)
        {
            string toText = "sun";
            string toLang = "en";
            //string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Speak?text=" + toText + "&language=" + toLang +"&format=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("audio/wav") + "&options=MaxQuality";
            string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Speak?text=welcome&language=en&format=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("audio/wav") + "&options=MaxQuality";
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);
            WebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(stream))
                    {
                        player.PlaySync();
                        alpha.Text = "alpha";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    response.Close();
                    response = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I'm not able to play the file" doesn't say much about what's wrong there... Are there error messages ? What actually happens when you run your code ? Does debugging give any hints about something wrong ?

Comment: I'm working with .NET in the frontend, so i have another .ascx file that models the design view of the translator. I have gotten the Detect and Translate method to work, whereby i will input a some text in one textbox and the translated text will be generated into another textbox. I have a button beside, that invokes the above Speak Method, calling Microsoft's server which is supposed to return me a wav stream. With the above Speak Method, it should also immediately play the wav sound.

Comment: However, when i clicked the button, no sound could be heard and i'm sure my sound is working and i could do the same on bing translator's website without a problem. There are no apparent hints on any error because simply nothing happens. I've tried to inject a label "alpha.Text = "alpha";" just to make sure the code runs inside  the Soundplayer, and indeed the label is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but my wav generated file works fine in my WPF code in a windows 7 computer, but if I open it with Zune for some reason it gives me an error, with Windows Media Player in windows 7 it works fine too. But in a Windows xp computer it doesn't works.

Have you tried to open the generated wav file with a media player or in different OSs and Browsers?